# Codename One Android Build Error - permission#com.android.vending.BILLING

Tags: android, codenameone, billing

When I'm trying to do an Android build, it's giving me this error:

Merging result: ERROR
/tmp/build6250103586261222869xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:57:3-64 Error:
Element uses-permission#com.android.vending.BILLING at AndroidManifest.xml:57:3-64 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:56:5-92
/tmp/build6250103586261222869xxx/MyApplication/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

This is happening after I've added In App Purchase code, after successfully adding my android.licenseKey to the build hints.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I had uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" in the build hints. Taking it out fixed the issue. (I believe I had put it there, so that I was able to enable in-app purchase from the google play console).